How to get a Linux VM to pass MSAL SSO authentication?
I have a React app that uses the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) to identify users. It works just fine on my Windows machine; however, for a variety of reasons, I'm trying to get a Linux VM set up to do certain development tasks. Unfortunately, its user isn't a "real" Active Directory user, so the app just hangs when I get to that step.
In Windows, I can simply right-click on an application and impersonate another user to run it. However, I haven't been able to figure out a good way to do that in Linux (especially given that it must be an Active Directory user). (In this case, I would like to do something similar with the web browser).
Does anyone know how I can do that?
I am using an Ubuntu machine if that makes any difference.

Any reason you do not enroll your Ubuntu machine into your Active Directory deployment?  That would give a real Active Directory user.

@GracefulRestart No, actually. Is there anything that I have to do from the Linux side in order to get that working, or just on the Active Directory side?

The main tool on the Linux side would be realmd to assist with the enrollment using SSSD.  You would also need to add your Ubuntu machine on the Active Directory side.  There are many tutorials on how to get Ubuntu setup with Active Directory, if you get stuck you can submit another question about what you need help with on the Linux side.
